Children run in midair, stone bricks appear at their feet to create a castle
Does anyone know this movie? It's animated but not Japanese.
These four children are travelling with this older creepy dude. Near the end they run around in midair and stone bricks appear at their feet. They create a castle this way but it has no gargoyles.
At the very end they trade 1 year from the end of each of their lives in exchange for the creepy dude sparing their friend, who they were chasing apparently the whole movie. Then they chew these tablets to seal the deal.
Some time travel and/or thieving may have been involved.

You're looking for The Halloween Tree from 1993.

Four children learn the origins of Halloween customs while trying to save the life of their friend. 

The creepy old man is Mr. Moundshroud, there's a scene where the kids are running on floating bricks, and in the end:

Moundshroud, holding Pip's pumpkin, tells the children they did not make it in time and Pip is now his property, symbolized by Pip's pumpkin. The children, eager to have their friend back, offer a year from each of their lives in exchange for Pip's.

Here's a compilation of scenes from the film:



